# Paste rich text with formating

Tags: windows-7, clipboard

I would like to be able to paste rich text that I've copied (for example) from a webpage directly into notepad (or other plain text box) and retain details like urls etc.

For example, if I copied text from a webpage that read "[Stackexchange](https://stackexchange.com/)" (notice how it has a clickable link to "http://stackexchange.com"), pasting to wordpad or some office program, will paste as clickable text. It would be great to be able to paste directly in notepad as

```
http://stackexchange.com Stackexchange
```

or

```
<a href="http://stackexchange.com">Stackexchange</a>
```

or similar.

I thought a clipboard manager should be able to do this, so I tried CLC and ArsClip. In CLC I could at least see the raw html but no obvious way to get that on to the clipboard. I could save it to a file, but that's not practical.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/484214/filter-rich-text-on-clipboard may be a related question

Comment: Well, copy the source code instead.

Comment: that works okay in some circumstances ayckoster, e.g. firefox - but doesn't work so well when using ctrl+click to select table cells nor when using chrome

Comment: or other rich-text programs like pdf readers, (open)office, etc

Comment: In chrome just right click provides option "Copy Link Address", will it not do the purpose ?

Comment: I love this question and don't think anyone has really answered it very well. I wish some program or plugin would enable me to copy/paste from rich text to plain text but have hyperlinks converted to something like `StackExchange[http://stackexchange.com]`, which is what email systems do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using "Paste Special"

Notepad++ has an option, [Edit, Paste Special, Paste HTML Content]. Copying from various browsers gives different results. I've copied the same section from your question in each browser, and pasted it into Notepad++.

From Firefox:

```
Version:0.9
StartHTML:00000177
EndHTML:00000550
StartFragment:00000211
EndFragment:00000514
SourceURL:http://superuser.com/questions/570820/paste-rich-text-with-formating
<html><body>
<!--StartFragment-->For example, if I copied text from a webpage that read "Stackexchange" and was a clickable link to "<a href="http://stackexchange.com">http://stackexchange.com</a>",
 pasting to wordpad or some office program, will paste as clickable 
text. It would be great to be able to paste directly in notepad as<!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```

From Chrome:

```
Version:0.9
StartHTML:0000000185
EndHTML:0000002191
StartFragment:0000000221
EndFragment:0000002155
SourceURL:http://superuser.com/questions/570820/paste-rich-text-with-formating
<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment--><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, 'Liberation Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 18px; orphans: auto; text-align: left; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: auto; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: inline !important; float: none;">For example, if I copied text from a webpage that read "Stackexchange" and was a clickable link to "</span><a href="http://stackexchange.com/" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(19, 179, 189); text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; font-family: Arial, 'Liberation Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 18px; orphans: auto; text-align: left; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: auto; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">http://stackexchange.com</a><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, 'Liberation Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 18px; orphans: auto; text-align: left; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: auto; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: inline !important; float: none;">", pasting to wordpad or some office program, will paste as clickable text. It would be great to be able to paste directly in notepad as</span><!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```

From IE:

```
Version:1.0
StartHTML:000000231
EndHTML:000005122
StartFragment:000004682
EndFragment:000004996
StartSelection:000004682
EndSelection:000004996
SourceURL:http://superuser.com/questions/570820/paste-rich-text-with-formating
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>windows 7 - Paste rich text with formating - Super User</TITLE><LINK 
rel="shortcut icon" 
href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/superuser/img/favicon.ico"><LINK 
rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" 
href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/superuser/img/apple-touch-icon.png"><LINK 
title="Super User" rel=search type=application/opensearchdescription+xml 
href="/opensearch.xml">
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript 
src="http://engine.adzerk.net/z/8476/adzerk1_2_4_46,adzerk2_2_17_47?keywords=windows-7,clipboard" 
async="true"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js" 
async="true"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js" 
async="true"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript 
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript 
src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=1f945f8e69cb"></SCRIPT>
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css 
href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/superuser/all.css?v=8eaaa600ccef"><LINK 
rel=canonical 
href="http://superuser.com/questions/570820/paste-rich-text-with-formating"><LINK 
title="Feed for question 'Paste rich text with formating'" rel=alternate 
type=application/atom+xml href="/feeds/question/570820">
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>

        StackExchange.ready(function () {
            StackExchange.using("postValidation", function () {
                StackExchange.postValidation.initOnBlurAndSubmit($('#post-form'), 2, 'answer');
            });


            StackExchange.question.init({hasOpenBounty:true,showAnswerHelp:true,totalCommentCount:4,shownCommentCount:4,highlightColor:'#BEB013',backgroundColor:'#FFF',questionId:570820});

            styleCode();

                StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToQuestion('3', '570820');


        });
    </SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
        StackExchange.ready(function () {
            StackExchange.realtime.init('ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com:80');
            StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToInboxNotifications();
                    StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToReputationNotifications('3');
                });
    </SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
        StackExchange.init({"stackAuthUrl":"https://stackauth.com","serverTime":1366208314,"enableUserHovercards":true,"site":{"name":"Super User","description":"Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users","isNoticesTabEnabled":true,"recaptchaPublicKey":"6LcDNwYAAAAAAG_X1rC8kTtLBP6XS2Ym1N0n9kSY","useNewStyleFavoriteTagsEditor":true,"enableSocialMediaInSharePopup":true},"user":{"fkey":"edbc1fe628205ffa4db5a492350fc54b","isAnonymous":true}});
        StackExchange.using.setCacheBreakers({"js/prettify-full.js":"6c261bebf56a","js/moderator.js":"f96f7e4ee5dc","js/full-anon.js":"4aa778f20142","js/full.js":"2cb347042411","js/wmd.js":"605c62dd1a01","js/third-party/jquery.autocomplete.min.js":"e5f01e97f7c3","js/mobile.js":"6eb68240242f","js/help.js":"fc9fb0517db2","js/tageditor.js":"450c9e8426fc","js/tageditornew.js":"b6c68ad4c7dd","js/inline-tag-editing.js":"8e84e8a137f7","js/revisions.js":"7273bb714bba","js/review.js":"5b2105439221","js/tagsuggestions.js":"aa48ef6154df","js/post-validation.js":"98fa812e7e1a","js/explore-qlist.js":"6c836f42bd92"});

    </SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
        StackExchange.using("gps", function() {
             StackExchange.gps.init(true);
        });
    </SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript 
src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full-anon.js?v=4aa778f20142" 
async="async"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript 
src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/post-validation.js?v=98fa812e7e1a" 
async="async"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript 
src="http://static.adzerk.net/Extensions/adFeedback.js"></SCRIPT>
<LINK rel=stylesheet 
href="http://static.adzerk.net/Extensions/adFeedback.css"></HEAD>

<BODY class=question-page jQuery17103772600276367371="4">

<DIV class=container>

<DIV id=content>

<DIV itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" itemscope>

<DIV id=mainbar>

<DIV id=question class=question jQuery17103772600276367371="12" 
data-questionid="570820">

<TABLE>

<TBODY>

<TR>

<TD class=postcell>

<DIV>

<DIV class=post-text itemprop="description"><!--StartFragment--><P>For example, if I copied text from a webpage that read "Stackexchange" and 
was a clickable link to "<A 
href="http://stackexchange.com">http://stackexchange.com</A>", pasting to 
wordpad or some office program, will paste as clickable text. It would be great 
to be able to paste directly in notepad as</P><!--EndFragment--></DIV>
</DIV>
</TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice but pspad also has this feature.

Comment: I wish the `Edit > Paste Special > Paste Binary Content` would paste (or a separate option were available to paste) from rich text to plain text but have hyperlinks converted to something like `Stackexchange[http://stackexchange.com]`, which is what email systems do.

Answer (score 1):

For your example about web pages, you can use Chrome and the developer tools :

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>    to inspect the part you want to copy, and then in Elements explorer, right click on the node you want and choose Copy as HTML.

[image: example of html copy]

Answer (score 0):

#### For Chrome:

Easiest way is to Right Click on the hyperlink. From Context menu Select option `Inspect Element` then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy the link along with HTML formatting.

**Alternatively:**

I have created a [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) script to automate the whole process with just single Hotkey (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>):

```
^m::
MouseClick, right
Sleep, 1000
Send, {DOWN  6}{ENTER}
Sleep, 1000
Send, {CTRLDOWN}c{CTRLUP}
```

With above script placing mouse on hyperlink and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> will copy the formatted link to clipboard.

---

#### For Firefox:

- Keep mouse on link, then Right Click.
- Press Q (or select Inspect Element).
- Select `Copy Outer HTML` from drop down. Your link will be copied along with HTML formatting.

[image: Firefox copy link address]