# Paste as HTML in Windows 10

Tags: windows, html, clipboard

On Windows 10, is there a way to paste the current clipboard content as html to (any) plain text editor, with html tags, assuming that the clipboard contains something in html format? E.g. perhaps there is some kind of utility that registers a global hotkey to "paste as html" which takes the html content of clipboard and pastes it with all tags?

The only workaround I know is to use an app that gives access to clipboard (e.g. InsideClipboard) and copy the html manually from there. But it is rather slow for a lot of copy paste operations.

Comment: Why not just copy the HTML

Comment: I only have access to rich formatted text, which I can copy to clipboard. I can't access its html source directly. But once in clipboard, the html version is available there, as well as rich format and plain text.

Comment: Notepad++ can do this. Please see this answer: https://superuser.com/a/584090/21852

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paste rich text with formating](https://superuser.com/questions/570820/paste-rich-text-with-formating)