# MS Word, paste hyperlink with text to display

Tags: microsoft-word, zotero

I would like to know how to format a link that when it is manually pasted (in this case from Zotero) into MS Word it displays custom text (text to display) and links it to the URL, like if you copy this link (not copy as link) to MS Word [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

I tried to use the reverse approach from [Paste rich text with formating](https://superuser.com/questions/570820/paste-rich-text-with-formating) but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to create a hyperlink with custom text ?

If that is correct,

1. Highlight the text you want to hyperlink,
2. Press Ctrl+K on your keyboard to open the Insert Hyperlink dialog in Word,
3. In the address field at the bottom, enter the website URL, and press enter.

I tried it in Word online and on the Desktop app and it works for me. Here is a link to more info in [Microsoft's documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-a-screen-reader-to-insert-a-hyperlink-in-word-df265db8-b1ec-4691-9cd5-b8826b5d5480?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#PickTab=Web)

Comment: Please give more details rather than simply a link, even if the link tells all.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon is this better?

Comment: Yes, it is. See my response as well (which is probably overboard).

Answer (score 0):

After copying the link, right click in the destination document where you want to insert the formatted link. You should see the following:

[image]

The first option of an clipboard icon with paint brush will paste the object and keep its source formatting. Hover your cursor over each of the Paste icons to see an explanation of what it will do.

Comment: This is not what I want. I want to format a link, in non html document, and copy it to word in a manner where "Text to display" and "Address" field will be populated as if I copied it from a html named link, like the example above of "Superuser" link.

Answer (score 0):

### Hyperlinks in Word have multiple parts, just as in HTML

This is probably most easily seen looking at the Insert Hyperlink dialog. You can view this dialog using `Ctrl`+`K` or `Insert` > `Links` > `Hyperlink`. You do not need this to paste a hyperlink but it is useful to see.

[image: screenshot insert hyperlink dialog]

That inserts the hyperlink [Global Templates in Microsoft Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global). The URL or address is `http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global`. It is directing to a bookmark `Global` in the page. It looks like this when entered:

[image: screenshot]

Hyperlinks are fields, most of which you can see by toggling field codes `Alt` + `F9` in Windows. This one looks like this:

[image: screenshot of field code]

Notice that the Display Text is not shown in the field as displayed even though it is clearly there. This is a defect in this field display.

If there is a screentip it will be shown.

[image: screenshot of dialog with screentip]

[image: screenshot of screentip showing in document]

[image: screenshot of field code with screentip]

You can get back to the dialog which would show the display text by editing the Hyperlink.

### Back to your question

When you paste into word, what you need to do depends on what it is you paste.

- If it is a live hyperlink with display text and possibly a bookmark, you would want to use the **Merge Formatting** option as shown in an earlier answer.
- If it is a bare text URL you would want to simply paste as text, select it and use the `Ctrl`+`K` shortcut to add your display text.
- If it is the name or display text, you would again simply paste as text, select it and use the `Ctrl`+`K` shortcut to add your URL or Address.